# Linking Point input data with SAGA Upslope input in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, saga, qgis-expression

I have a model set up with a point input.  I need the point's x and y coordinate data to populate the x-value and y-value fields required as input for the SAGA upslope function.

I have tried various expressions, but just can't seem to get it right.

I have seen other posts with similar questions, but I'm missing the final link.
[image: Model Outline]